# Spark TwitterStream, filter tweets by location

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

I'm trying to get tweets in specific area.
I'm using Spark 1.6.1(Scala) and Twitter4J 4.0.4.
The beginning of the programs is standard(keys etc.)
I created a stream with TwitterUtils like:

```
val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filter, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)
```

I found on my researches **FilterQuery** and tried
to use it in **filter** method of tweetStream, but it does not accept it.

What I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you debug TwitterInputDStream.scala, in particular:

```html
      val query = new FilterQuery
      if (filters.size > 0) {
        query.track(filters.mkString(","))
        newTwitterStream.filter(query)
      } else {
        newTwitterStream.sample()
      }
```

The only possibility to filter twitter stream is based on keywords as only track() method is used. I've tried this to search for particular hashtags, that worked.

Comment: Thank you Taras for explanation. So you do not know if it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 0):

Who is interested to filter by location I found a workaround.

Each tweet has geoLocation(lat. / long.)
Other useful field is Place. It has many fields that can be filtered by like: 'Country', 'CountryCode', 'City' etc.

The only drawback that it is filtered after you receive a tweet and not in Twitter's side.